# How to properly add MFC Link Control to Dialog?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

I made a plugin DLL for a game. Now I want to add License activation to my plugin, so I made a simple Dialog (LicenseActivation.rc) using Visual Studio resource wizard.

When DLL is being attached I save HMODULE as `m_hModule` member variable, and I run the following code in a new thread

```
DialogBox(m_hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, About);
```

And the `About` callback function is implemented as follows

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PrintDebug(L"About(%d, %#x, %d, %d)", hDlg, message, wParam, lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        //PrintDebug(L"case WM_INITDIALOG");
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        //PrintDebug(L"case WM_COMMAND");
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

And this is the Dialog resource

[image: Dialog in the Visual Studio 2015 Editor]

Before I add **MFC Link Control** element to the **Dialog** it works just fine, the Dialog is being shown when run and prints the following debug messages

```
[11848] About(1380712, 0x30, 1544171096, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x110, 6359660, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x46, 0, 253295812)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x1c, 1, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x86, 0, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x7f, 2, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x7f, 0, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x7f, 1, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x6, 1, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x400, 0, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x127, 3, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x128, 196609, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x31f, 1, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x18, 1, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x46, 0, 253296052)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x85, 1, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x7f, 2, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x7f, 0, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x7f, 1, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x14, 16855179, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x136, 16855179, 1380712)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x47, 0, 253296052)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x7f, 2, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x7f, 0, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x7f, 1, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0xf, 0, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x135, 16855179, 6359660)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x135, 16855179, 1445800)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x138, 16855179, 1446218)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x133, 16855179, 2363706)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x133, 16855179, 2363706)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x138, 16855179, 1577080)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x7f, 2, 96)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x7f, 0, 96)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x7f, 1, 96)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x7f, 2, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x7f, 0, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x7f, 2, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x7f, 0, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x7f, 2, 0)
[11848] About(1380712, 0x7f, 0, 0)
```

but as soon as I add **MFC Link Control** to the **Dialog**, the Dialog doesn't appear and prints the following debug messages

```
[9748] About(3018840, 0x30, 1393179198, 0)
[9748] About(3018840, 0x90, 0, 0)
[9748] About(3018840, 0x2, 0, 0)
[9748] About(3018840, 0x82, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see you have a plain Win32 program.

The Link Control is only available for MFC projects. You have neither a dialog that is derived from CDialogEx nor are you using any technique to create or handle the controls in the way the MFC does.

There is a plain hyper link control for win32 [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13505/Win32-C-Easy-Hyper-Link) and [here](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/staticctrl/article.php/c5803/Transforming-Static-Text-Controls-into-Active-Hyperlinks-Using-the-Win32-API.htm).

Comment: Does this mean that it is not possible to make it work without writing a single line of code for the hyperlink? When I go to Format > Test Dialog (CTR+T) inside VS it works just fine. Is this normal? I am wondering why VS does not complain or give any hints about this.

Comment: No. This is special MFC stuff. And you are not using MFC! The test-container is MFC aware. Windows itself doesn't have such a link control. I added another code sample to my answer.

Comment: What are those two links you added? Windows has native [SysLink control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/syslink-control-entry) available for Vista and up. "SysLink Control" is in dialog design box, next to "MFC Link Control"

Comment: @xMRi Thank you for you reply, but, unfortunately your answer is a little bit complex for me. Is there any way I can make my DLL MFC aware?